# mv wrapped inside an if in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

How do you do this?
What I'm thinking is like this.. also, do I need to use fi and done? or only one of them

```
if[mv 1.txt > 2.txt == '0'] 
then
 echo "Success"
else
 echo "Failure"
fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In BASH only this would suffice:

```
mv 1.txt 2.txt && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"
```

However if you want to use traditional `if/fi` then use

```
if mv 1.txt 2.txt
then
  echo "Success"
else
  echo "Failure"
fi
```

Comment: How can I add fi after the first one? Because I get unexpected end of file without it i think.

Comment: First command I showed doesn't have `if/fi` only in 2nd version you can use as shown.

Answer (score 1):

```
if mv 1.txt 2.txt
then
  echo Success
else
  echo Failure
fi
```

`if` takes a command as its argument and executes the `then` clause if the command ran successfully, or the `else` clause if there was an error.  Interestingly, once upon a time, `[` was a command that evaluated the conditions you handed to it, and it is probably still available on your system -- check out `/usr/bin/[`.

If you don't have a `do` statement, you don't need a `done` statement.  `fi` is required as the final statement of an `if` command.