# mv wrapped inside an if in bash script - strange behavior

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I try to automate moving my files from 1 folder to another in a for loop. Checking in a if-clause if the directory already exists, else create it and similar I wanted to check if the move was successfull else writing a error log.

```
if mv "$file" $destinationPath"$nameAnime/$nameAnimeEp"
then
    writeLogfile "moved"
    echo "moved"
    ((countFiles++))
else
    writeLogfile "Error"
fi
```

As I already looked into it here: [mv wrapped inside an if in shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23255565/mv-wrapped-inside-an-if-in-shell-scripting)
Could you please help me to see where my mistake is? Because my logfile looked like this:

> 16.11.2017 15:30:02 CET - moved
>   16.11.2017 15:30:02 CET - Error
>   5 more tries
>   16.11.2017 15:30:02 CET - moved

Stopped after the last one. I guess the file was still in use as my script tried to move the file, but thats ok. Whats not is that it should not write the log "moved" if it couldn't move. I got a similar if with mkdir where it's working as intended. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Provided that your variables have reasonable values, there is nothing wrong in your code. However, you make yourself your life more difficult than necessary: Instead of outputting just "Error", the very least you should print is the arguments of the mv command. In addition, you seem to throw away your stderr: If mv returns an exit code different from zero, it must have also printed a message on stderr. This message will likely tell you what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out a probably very common mistake. After I read the "useless" error message in my logfile I already extended it like this `"Error: Couldn't move file \"$nameAnimeEp\" to \"$destinationPath$nameAnime\""` I just thought it's easier to read like the way I posted it.  
  
As for your second part I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. How would I be able to log the other exit code you mentioned?  
  
But you can't tell me alone from these informations why the both the if and else part were accessed?

Comment: While you could log the exit code of the `mv` command - the last exit code is always stored in `$?`, this was not the point. I wanted to express it like this: In your script, you are testing the exit code of the mv command - whether it is 0 or non-zero. If it is zero, you know of course that moving the file has succeeded. If it is **not** zero, it doesn't matter what its value is - you **know** for sure that there must be an error message written on stderr. Hence, in your program, you should have logged this error message in the `else` branch.